# Binary Search Tree unchangeable header file

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I'm doing an assignment on binary search trees. We are given a header file and we are not allowed to alter it.

I have a function for creating an BST with an initial value to store, a function to create a BST by copying an existing tree and a function to insert into a BST.

I am struggling to find out what's wrong, everywhere I look online for help always has differences in the header file which I can't do. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "bst.h"

// Creating nodes  
Node* tree;
Node* treeNew;


// Creates an empty binary tree - 1
BinarySearchTree::BinarySearchTree()
{
    treeNew = nullptr;
}

// Creates a binary tree with an initial value to store - 2
BinarySearchTree::BinarySearchTree(std::string word)
{
    Node *tree = new Node;
    tree->left = nullptr;
    tree->right = nullptr;
    tree->data = word;
}

// Creates a binary tree by copying an existing tree - 3
BinarySearchTree::BinarySearchTree(const BinarySearchTree &rhs)
{
    if (tree != NULL) {

        Node *treeNew = new Node;
        treeNew->data = tree->data;

        Node *leftTreeNew = new Node;
        leftTreeNew = tree->left;

        Node *rightTreeNew = new Node;
        rightTreeNew = tree->right;
    }
    else {
        treeNew = NULL;
    }
}

// Adds a word to the tree
void BinarySearchTree::insert(std::string word)
{
    Node *nextNode = tree;
    Node *currentNode;


    while (nextNode != NULL) {
        currentNode = nextNode;

        if (word < currentNode->data) {
            nextNode = currentNode->left;
        } else {
            nextNode = currentNode->right;
        }
    } 
}
```

here's my header file

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Node of the tree
struct Node
{
    // Data stored in this node of the tree
    std::string data;
    // The left branch of the tree
    Node *left = nullptr;
    // The right branch of the tree
    Node *right = nullptr;
};

class BinarySearchTree
{
private:
    // Pointer to root of the tree
    Node *root = nullptr;
public:
    // Creates an empty binary tree
    BinarySearchTree();
    // Creates a binary tree with an inital word to store
    BinarySearchTree(std::string word);
    // Creates a binary tree by copying an existing tree
    BinarySearchTree(const BinarySearchTree &rhs);
    // Destroys (cleans up) the tree
    ~BinarySearchTree();
    // Adds a word to the tree
    void insert(std::string word);
    // Removes a word from the tree
    void remove(std::string word);
    // Checks if a word is in the tree
    bool exists(std::string word) const;
    // Creates a string representing the tree in alphabetical order
    std::string inorder() const;
    // Creates a string representing the tree in pre-order
    std::string preorder() const;
    // Creates a string representing the tree in post-order
    std::string postorder() const;
    // Checks if two trees are equal
    bool operator==(const BinarySearchTree &other) const;
    // Checks if two trees are not equal
    bool operator!=(const BinarySearchTree &other) const;
    // Reads in words from an input stream into the tree
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &in, BinarySearchTree &tree);
    // Writes the words, in-order, to an output stream
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const BinarySearchTree &tree);
};
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @Jeffrey I have a test.cpp I can run to test if my functions work and it fails every time, they just don't work and I don't know why

Comment: You code is not using what is in the class define in the header.  For instance, where do you set the member variable root in your code?

Comment: "they just don't work and I don't know why" is a far cry from a proper problem description. *How* don't they work? What did you expect? What did you observe? What did you learn while stepping through the code with your debugger?

Comment: `Node* tree; Node* treeNew;` -- Why are you declaring globals here?  You're cheating by creating your own set of global variables "on the side", building your own version of tree, and not using the class member variables declared in the header.  By using globals, you're creating something outside of the class, thus violating the basic rule of encapsulation.  I suggest you remove those two variables, and start over, given that the only thing you have to work with is the class itself, and any local variables you may want to use within the class functions.

Answer (score 0):

There are many mistakes with your code, and you need to correct them.

For example,

1. Within the function insert(std::string word), if the tree is null, there is nothing to be done, but in fact you should create a node(with the value of "word") and insert it. similarly, the root may change sometimes, and you must consider it.
2. Within the function BinarySearchTree(const BinarySearchTree &rhs), you never use rhs. Further, I guess you mean that a deep dopy, so your code can't work at all.

My advice is that you should rewrite your function(after making a full understanding of BST). Meanwhile, you may describe your question clearly asap.